# AWS Lambda layers exceeding memory - gensim, pandas, nltk, scipi

Tags: aws-lambda

I am running into this issue while creating my lambda:

> Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes

These are my requirements for the code.

```
gensim==4.1.2
nltk==3.6.7
numpy==1.22.1
pandas==1.4.0
scipy==1.7.3
```

Has anyone deployed a lambda using these libraries before?

The unzipped layers file is more than 250 mb. Is there any way to include all these libraries?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can now package the Lambda function as a container image. In that case, you can use up to 10 GB of space.

You can see more details in the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/) but basically, you create a docker image as you would normally and publish it to some registry, like ECR.